# Angular Form validation not working inside controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, validation

I am trying to validate angularjs form from controller like this below:

**My Form:**

```
<form name="appGroupForm" class="form-horizontal">
    <input id="unique-name" ng-model="appGroup.name" name="name" type="text"
       placeholder="New App Group" class="form-control input-md"
       ng-trim="false" ng-pattern="/[^\s]+/"
       ng-change="uniqueAppGroupName()"
       required />
</form>
```

**Controller:**

```
$scope.uniqueAppGroupName = function () {
    $scope.appGroupForm.name.$setValidity('unique', true);
};
```

But it throws error as:

`TypeError: Cannot read property '$setValidity' of undefined`

Also tried with:

```
$scope.appGroupForm.name.$setValidity.unique = !error;
```

But still no success, Any ideas & suggestions for this cause?

Comment: show us your form html

Comment: That message means that `$scope.form.formname` is undefined.

Comment: `forrmname` is your field name ?

Comment: I have edited my question with actual code. Please have a look

Comment: Posted code works fine, the issue is not reproducible.

Comment: yes code woking fine in plnkr. http://plnkr.co/edit/T6t7aNPtGYENqfvAxHmm?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

try `$scope.appGroupForm.unique-name.$setValidity('unique-name', true);`
EDIT: 
`$scope.appGroupForm[name].$setValidity('unique-name', true);`

Comment: Error: `TypeError: name.$setValidity is not a function`. I dont think we can work on id and variables be created using eiphens as well

Comment: @Hansie Hmm try this `$scope.appGroupForm[name].$setValidity('unique-name', true);`